# Django collectstatic and Apache issue

Tags: django, apache

I use this command:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

to collect all static files from all applications and upload them to one single folder `apps/apps/static/`. So, I now have this file tree:

```
\home
  \jacobian
     \apps     // <-- this is the root folder of my Django project
        \apps
         settings.py
         urls.py
         ...
         \static
```

The command `collectstatic` works fine - I see how it uploads all necessary files. But the problem is, I do not know how to force Apache now to load static files from that single `\static` folder. I tried to add these lines to my `mysite.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ....
    AliasMatch ^/js(.*) /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static$1
    Alias /static/ /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static

</VirtualHost>
```

But is does not work. When I restart Apache and reload the page (which itself contains the link `src="/js/test.js"`) in browser, I see in the console:

```
localhost/home/jacobian/apps/apps/static/js/test.js   [HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND]
```

although it seems that the url is resolved correctly, for some reason Apache is unable to upload static content from there. And by the way, what I also do not like about this is that the server discards `home/jacobian/` part of the url.

**EDIT**

apache conf file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

AliasMatch ^/js(.*) /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static$1

Alias /static/ /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static

DocumentRoot /home/jacobian/apps/apps

<Directory /home/jacobian/apps/apps/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>

<Directory /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jacobian/apps/apps/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is what I have in Django project `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/home/jacobian/apps/apps/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/jacobian/apps/apps/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

**EDIT**

I also tried this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

AliasMatch ^/js(.*) /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static$1

Alias /static/ /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jacobian/apps/apps/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/jacobian/apps/apps>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

but still get the very same error `localhost/static/js/test.js [HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND]`, even though there is a file `/home/jacobian/apps/apps/static/js/test.js`. I have a guess that it might be somehow related to the `DEBUG` mode in settings.py. Maybe I should do some extra magic with `urls.py`?

Comment: What permissions are set on every folder in path for that file? Also what owner that files have? What are permissions on that particular file and on what user and group apache is running?

Comment: Each folder in the path from `/jacobian/`.... down to `/jacobian/apps/apps/static/` has these permissions - `drwxrwxr-x` and has `jacobian` as an owner

Comment: As for apache, it is running as `www-data`

Comment: Can you show also whole apache config file?

Comment: You might need a `<Directory>` section to allow access to the `static/` folder. Also, from the docs: "Note that if you include a trailing / on the URL-path then the server will require a trailing / in order to expand the alias."

Comment: `STATIC_URL` should be `/static/`, i.e. the public url for static files.

Comment: @knbk. I changed it and restarted Apache, but it did not help. In the console I see, that it now tries to load files from `localhost/static/js/test.js` - and it looks nice and promissing, but for some reason Apache throws again `NOT FOUND` error.

Comment: I guess there may be some additional extra magic in `urls.py`, somewhere in the project folder - `apps/apps/urls.py` - some handler or view to deal with this route `static/` - but I do not know what exactly should I do.

Comment: Why are you trying to get file `/js/test.js`? All static files are inside `/static/` directory, other paths will be handled by django. So correct path should be `/static/js/test.js`.

Comment: @GwynBleidD  Because inside applications I separate js, css and img files, like `application1/static/js/test.js`, `application2/static/css/foo.css` etc.

Comment: "Why are you trying to get file /js/test.js?" And if you mean the client code, then it does not matter, because in my case `AliasMatch` does the trick

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below.

Comment: @Matt. I do not have any answers in my question - I posted only attempts. You can see the answer below (by GwynBleidD)

Comment: @Jacobian: You had edited a solution into your question; http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32746080/revisions. The reason it is not there now is because I have already edited it out.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure whether you did a good job or not. The actual solution is below. And my extra comment was supposed to provide the full picture based on that answer. I did not have any intention to prepare an answer myself. So, for newcomers and for those who are seeking answers, I think you did a bad job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your `STATIC_URL` to: `'/static/'`. That should be URL on what Apache serves your static files, not system directory path.

Second, remove `DocumentRoot` from your apache config. All files outside of static directories should be handled by wsgi.

Third, change:

```
<Directory /home/jacobian/apps/apps/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory /home/jacobian/apps/apps>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

You don't want to serve all your files, just wsgi.py should be accessed publicly, and handled by WSGI. Also try to move that block below `WSGIScriptAlias`.

Fourth, remove trailing slash at the end of path in `<Directory /home/jacobian/apps/apps/>`.

Fifth, change `allow,deny` to `deny,allow`.

Comment: So, it should be `deny,allow` inside Files tag?

Comment: Yes. It might be irrelevant change, but that is configuration working for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it in a minute!

Comment: Please, have a look at the updated version of my question. Thanks!

Comment: Where does the block `<Directory /home/jacobian/apps/apps/static>` disappeared?

Comment: Or, sorry. Will check it in a second.

Comment: Try also to add / at the end of `Alias` directive

Comment: Pheeeew, it is working!! Thank you, sir! You saved my day. For starters like me, I will post the whole version of the configuration file.